# visualize IOPS using metricbeat and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat

I am using metricbeat to calculate system disk io data. I can not calculate and visualize IO per second of the system. I am new to elasticsearch stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the new Kibana [Time Series Visual Builder](https://www.elastic.co/blog/master-time-with-kibanas-new-time-series-visual-builder). It was build having (also) Metricbeat data in mind.

Comment: The time series builder is problematic because you cannot group by two things, e.g. host and device.

Comment: Also, there is no explicit IOP metric, and system.diskio.write_count derivative doesn't appear to really be IOPs that people are accustomed to